# Can I run Visual Studio unit tests on a running WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to run unit tests on various methods in a WPF application under MainWindow.xaml.cs. The problem I'm running into is that to access these methods I need an instance of the MainWindow, so I need to initialize an instance of the App.

When I call `App.Run()` I can't run any of my unit tests after this point until the application shuts down. Is there a way I can put this in some sort of background task so that I can interact with this running instance through unit tests, or will I need to restructure the code into MVVM code structure?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
AppInstance = new App();
AppInstance.InitializeComponent();
Task appRunTask = new Task(() => AppInstance.Run());
appRunTask.Start();

// Various unit test initialization and test methods.
```

**Edit:**
No longer necessary, found a work around by not using unit tests at this time.

Comment: *"to access these methods I need an instance of the MainWindow"* - I am not using unit-testing yet, but this sounds to me as the application is not unit-testable.. yet.

Comment: You need to restructure your code as you say to MVVM and test your ViewModels.

Comment: Or do you want to do UITests?